# Azure Function V2 JWT - AD Authentication

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-functions, azure-authentication

I am trying to authenticate the Azure Functions v2. I am getting below error 

 `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'WebJobsAuthLevel'. The registered schemes are: Bearer. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("WebJobsAuthLevel",...)?.`

below is the code I am using in Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,o =>
                    {
                        o.Audience = "https://*******************.azurewebsites.net/";
                        o.Authority = "http://localhost:****";
                        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            RequireSignedTokens = true,
                            ValidAudience = "https://***************.azurewebsites.net/",
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/***************-5********2**/",
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true
                        };
                    });
        }

    }
```

changed the code but still getting same given error. Which one I am missing?

Comment: Seems like it is looking for an authentication scheme with that name. You have named the JWT scheme with its default name. Maybe try setting its name to the one in the error? Also you are missing the Authority from the settings. Also your ValidAudience and ValidIssuer seem like they are not complete, did you remove those on purpose?

Comment: junnas- Please find the updated post. Still no luck. any suggestions.

Comment: Your authority should be e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-aad-tenant-id`. Add v2.0 to the end if you are using v2 endpoint of AAD. Oh and change your-aad-tenant-id to your azure ad tenant id of course :)

Comment: I don't think I need any authority because I am writing an HttpTrigger function. I need to authorize the API with Azure AD.

Comment: It's a standard property you need to set. Well, the other option is to set all the options, including signing keys manually, but why? Setting the authority makes the authentication handler download the issuer metadata from AAD so you don't need to set things like valid issuer or valid signing keys, all that is taken care of.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have access to the  `IApplicationBuilder` only the `IWebJobsBuilder`. With `IApplicationBuilder` you can do that: `app.UseAuthentication();`. This is what will enable auth on your app. I would stick with out of the box Azure AD Auth as stated by @connor-mcmahon

Comment: Thomas - Awesome catch. Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I saw some people trying to host a webapi inside a function: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1114. But personnaly I would stay away from this kind of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Azure App Service Authentication/Authorization feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) (also known unofficially as EasyAuth). If you follow the express flow in the Azure Portal, it will create an AAD V1 application registration for your function application, and automatically configure your app to allow authentication using AAD. If you then set `Action to take when request is not authenticated` to `Login with Azure Active Directory`, only authenticated requests will be authorized to make any request to your application.

EasyAuth has built in support for accepting Bearer tokens for your AAD app registration, as well as some other OAuth2/OIDC flows for AAD and our other supported identity providers (Facebook, Google, Twitter). Through this feature, you shouldn't need to add any code on your end, it will all be handled by the Azure platform.

Comment: when you write that EasyAuth has built-in support for Open-ID Connect flows, do you mean that we can setup a custom IdentityServer in the portal ? Is it officially supported ?

Comment: @LoulG, sorry the answer was worded vaguely. I mean that the OAauth and Open-ID Connect flows for Azure AD and our built in identity providers. We do have a work item we are considering for bring-your-own OpenID connect identity providers, but we do not have that feature at the moment. We are hoping to work on this feature soon, so stay tuned.